# PyQt5 memory leak with QPainter and QPixmap

Tags: python, qt, memory-leaks, pyqt5

I have the following code to create a Qpixmap of all desktop monitors:

```py
    def capture_desktop(self, app: QApplication):
        desktop_pixmap = QPixmap(QApplication.desktop().size())
        painter = QPainter(desktop_pixmap)
        for screen in app.screens():
            painter.drawPixmap(
                screen.geometry().topLeft(),
                screen.grabWindow(0),  # type: ignore
            )
        return desktop_pixmap
```

The code is mostly translated from the C++ code from this post: https://forum.qt.io/topic/95705/screenshot-selection/4

While my code does what it's intended to do, it causes a massive memory leak (about 30MB per invocation).

I thought it might be the QPainter leaking, so I tried manually calling `painter.end()` but this returns `True` and the memory leak is still there.

```py
    def capture_desktop(self, app: QApplication):
        desktop_pixmap = QPixmap(QApplication.desktop().size())
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(desktop_pixmap)
        for screen in app.screens():
            painter.drawPixmap(
                screen.geometry().topLeft(),
                screen.grabWindow(0),  # type: ignore
            )
        print(painter.end()) # returns True
        return desktop_pixmap
```

Comment: How are measuring the memory leak? Have you tried to call `del painter` after `painter.end()`? Also note that a painter is usually created with the paint device in the constructor (I believe that the `begin()` is still provided for backward compatibility): `painter = QPainter(desktop_pixmap)` should be enough, and it doesn't require calling `begin()`: `end()` is still required in most cases if the paint device has to be saved (like `QPixmap.save()`), but can be ignored for normal widget painting operation like `paintEvent` implementation since the painter is automatically gc at the end.

Comment: @musicamante I'm measuring it by looking at the `RES` column in `htop`, but just to make sure I also confirmed it by looking at `grep ^VmHWM /proc/546894/status` with the id of my process.

I tried calling `del painter`, it sadly made no difference.

Comment: This does not necessarily indicate memory leak. The memory allocated by the process is not immediately released and returned back to the operating system. Sometimes the process may hold some memory for reuse. Sometimes the memory is released after some time. What does happen if you try to call it, say, a thousand times? Does it fill up whole RAM and crash? Or does it still keep some extra 30 MB or so?

Comment: @V.K. Thank you for those tips!
I have found that the memory leak was actually in a different location and I was able to remove it, even though I do not understand it.
        `self.desktopPixmap = capture_desktop(app)`
        `label = QLabel()`
        `label.setPixmap(self.desktopPixmap)`
        `layout = QHBoxLayout()`
        `layout.addWidget(label)`

I had to remove the last 4 lines (the layout was not even added to the parent object) and this fixed the problem.
It seems I misunderstood what the painter actually does.